# Appengine throwing BadRequestError: The property.name is the empty string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an application that has worked successfully in the past. Today however, it's started throwing an error when I try write to datastore. For example, I'm creating a new entity of this model

```
    class EventInstallment(ndb.Model):
        somekey = ndb.KeyProperty()
        somename = ndb.StringProperty(default = "")
        start_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
        notes = ndb.StringProperty("")

        moderator_approved = ndb.BooleanProperty(default = True)
        added_by = ndb.KeyProperty()

        created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

using this code

```
    ins = somemodel()
    ins.somename = "26-september-2016"
    ins.somekey = the_key
    ins.start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    ins.put()
```

and this exception gets thrown.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 363, in post
        exec(compiled_code, globals())
      File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3451, in _put
        return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 383, in get_result
        self.check_success()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
        value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 824, in put
        key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
        value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 358, in _put_tasklet
        keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 513, in _on_rpc_completion
        result = rpc.get_result()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
        return self.__get_result_hook(self)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1881, in __put_hook
        self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1373, in check_rpc_success
        raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
    BadRequestError: The property.name is the empty string.
```

Any idea what this issue might be? It looks like a change in GAE ndb - as it worked as recently as 1 month ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't `notes = ndb.StringProperty("")` be: `notes = ndb.StringProperty(default = "")` ?

Comment: Oh my goodness! You are right!? Weird that it worked before and locally. But fixing that fixed the issue in production. You rock!!